# How to removeDialog(int dialogID) Android?

Tags: android, background, dialog

I have extended my class with a dialog in which I have set content view and other button actionlisteners etc... what is happening is that when I create my dialog it shows background properly.

but opening it again and again is crating problems with content view, things are added haphazardly and most of the UI elements are repeating and background image is disappeared.

I know that dialog is created once and is used as a cache, I don't want that I know there is a method in Android Activity removeDialog(int dialogID) but I don't know who to use this, I don't give any id to my dialog I don't know how to give id to dialog.

```
#dialog code

public class OptionsDailog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {
        public OptionsDailog(Activity pContext) {
        super(pContext, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        mContext = pContext;
        setContentView(R.layout.option_menu);
        setBasicContents();
    }

#options_menu.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/rl_root_option_menu">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/bg_episode" android:id="@+id/rl_option_screen">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_options" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerInParent="true">
            <Button android:text="Achievements" android:textSize="18sp" android:id="@+id/btn_achievements" android:background="@drawable/bg_options_menu" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:layout_width="250dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
            <Button android:text="Tutorial" android:textSize="18sp" android:id="@+id/btn_tutorial" android:background="@drawable/bg_options_menu" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:layout_width="250dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
            <Button android:text="Leaderboard" android:textSize="18sp" android:id="@+id/btn_leaderboard" android:background="@drawable/bg_options_menu" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:layout_width="250dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/btn_music" android:text="Music" android:textSize="18sp" android:background="@drawable/bg_options_menu" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:layout_width="250dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/btn_sound" android:textSize="18sp" android:text="Sound" android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" android:background="@drawable/bg_options_menu" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:layout_width="250dp" android:layout_height="60dp"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ImageButton android:background="@drawable/btn_back" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/ib_back_options_menu"></ImageButton>
</RelativeLayout>

#Dialog showing code
final OptionsDailog mDailog = new OptionsDailog(JungleCrashLand.this);
            mDailog.show();
```

Comment: I have overridden dismiss() and I also want to remove this dialog

Comment: did u do super.dismiss() after overriding (just an idea)

Comment: basically just do public void dismiss(){super.dismiss()... **whatever u want to do** }

Comment: Yeh I am calling super but on dismiss i also want to remove this dialog too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dialog class works with its own set of identifiers. If you create a dialog with createDialog(int x) you can pass this x as your own identifier. removing the dialog follows the same structure: removeDialog(int x) where x is, again, the identifier of your dialog type.  It is done this way to be able to distinguish between different "types" of dialogs, defined by your own, without the need to extend the dialog class.

so basically:

```
static final int OPTIONS_DIALOG = 0;
[...]
createDialog(OPTIONS_DIALOG);
[...]
removeDialog(OPTIONS_DIALOG);
```

as you can have only one dialog per activity, this will remove only this dialog and every(!) reference to it. Read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html to fully understand what is going on here.