# Dialog is not dismissing when calling dismissDialog

Tags: android

Hello i have a problem that `dismissDialog()` does not work when called.

I want my dialog to dismiss when back pressed.

I use this code to dismiss him:

```
public class InstaLoginDialog extends Dialog {


// SOME METHODS

public void onBackPressed() {

        InstaLoginDialog.this.dismissDialog();
            InstaLoginDialog.this.dismiss();
            InstaLoginDialog.this.cancel();

    }
}
```

On the part of of `onBackPressed()` its getting called but the dialog is not dismissed.

I tried all the dismiss methods.

Thank for helping

Comment: you could try removeDialog() instead!

Comment: there is not such method

Comment: right..from activity? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922791/how-to-removedialogint-dialogid-android

Comment: i dont see how its connected

Comment: Please list all tryed solutions, so its easier to answer. Also I guess the bug is not in the code provided. I recommend taking the official tut for DialogFragments from Google: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html since Dialogs are deprecated anyways - I guess then it will work.

Comment: I am surprised this question has bounty.

Answer (score 9):

Set dialog.cancelable(true) and you don't need to write any code to dismiss dialog on-back key press.

Answer (score 1):

dismissDialog() method was deprecated in API level 13

Have you tried `dismiss()`?

For e.g. `InstaLoginDialog.this.dismiss()`

---

**[EDIT]**

I've tried this code and it the dialog is dismissed when I press the back button. I have not used `onBackPressed()`

This is the `MyCustomDialog` class definition:

```
public class MyCustomDialog extends Dialog {

    public MyCustomDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    }
}
```

Then in my `MainActivity`, I invoke the dialog like this:

```
MyCustomDialog mydialog = new MyCustomDialog(MainActivity.this);
mydialog.show();
```

And when I press the back button my phone, the dialog is dismissed. Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it in your activity:

```
public class YourActivity extends FragmentActivity {

...

  public void onBackPressed() {
         dialog.dismiss();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one create constructor.

```
public InstaLoginDialog (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
```

**onBackPressed(**) used this one.

```
    InstaLoginDialog .this.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 1):

set only your_dialog.cancelable(true). Every thing will be handled by android itself.

```
your_dialog.cancelable(true)
```

For your concern.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent());
                            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Blocked");
                            alertDialogBuilder
                                    .setMessage("Seems like you are blocked by this service provider.Please choose another service provider.")
                                    .setCancelable(true)
                                .setNegativeButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                public void onClick(
                                                        DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int id) {
                                                    dialog.cancel();
                                                }
                                            });
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                            alertDialog.show();
```

If you need to cancel dialog using onBackPressed() then try

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
                your_dialog.dismiss();
}
```